# Laravel ignore unique validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a products table and unique column, but when I try to update it fails and show me unique error message.I try to make something to ignore, but does not work.

```
 $attributes = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|min:3',
            'description' => 'nullable|min:3',
            'selling_price' => 'required|numeric',
            'purchase_price' => 'required|numeric',
            'quantity' => 'required|integer',
            'unit' => 'nullable',
            'stock_alert' => 'nullable|numeric',
            'unique_code' => "required|unique:products,unique_code,$product->id",
            'awb' => 'required|numeric'
        ]);
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Store or update method? To make an update, take the id out of the quotation marks `"required|unique:products,unique_code,". $product->id`. To make store method, just `required|unique:products`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore a field like this

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

 $attributes = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|min:3',
            'description' => 'nullable|min:3',
            'selling_price' => 'required|numeric',
            'purchase_price' => 'required|numeric',
            'quantity' => 'required|integer',
            'unit' => 'nullable',
            'stock_alert' => 'nullable|numeric',
            'unique_code' => [
                "required",
                Rule::unique('products', 'unique_cod')->ignore($product->id),
             ],
            'awb' => 'required|numeric'
        ]);
```

Comment: It still fails, and show me this error message.The unique code has already been taken.

Comment: what is the primary key of products table ?

Comment: $table->bigIncrements('id');

Comment: can you make sure `$product->id` is the `id` of the record you have been updating

Comment: I used dd to display and it's the correct id.. I dont know why is not working.I am using route-model binding.

Comment: what is the field name of unique_code in products table ?

Comment: It is working, I had 2 rows with same unique_code, I delete the duplicate and it is working!

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring it isn't the right way. You use a validation for some reason.

To make an update, just take the product id out of the quotation marks like this:

`'unique_code' => 'required|unique:products,unique_code,'. $product->id,`

Comment: It still fails, and show me this error message.The unique code has already been taken.

Comment: ```'unique_code' => 'required|unique:products,unique_code,' .$product->id,```

Comment: Get the id of the product you want to update, for example 1000, change the validation to `'unique_code' => 'required|unique:products,unique_code,1000'`, check if it fails with that exact product, if not, you are not passing the id correctly.